# Filtering data from API using dropdown in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would I go about filtering results from an API using the dropdown?

I currently have a select tag like so

```
  <select value={selectMonthFilter} onChange={e=> setSelectMonthFilter(e.currentTarget.value)}>
    {console.log(selectMonthFilter)}
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="">Jan</option>
    <option value="">Feb</option>
    <option value="">Mar</option>
    ...
  </select>
```

The list is also displaying all the results from the API with

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const [selectMonthFilter, setSelectMonthFilter] = useState(data)
```

Example of what the API returns

```
{
"id": 1,
"first_name": "Bob",
"last_name": "Smith",
"birthdate": "1970-04-19T08:56:27Z",
},
```

Where 1970 is the year, 04 is the month, 19 is the day and the string after is time.

How would I implement so if the user selects Mar on the dropdown, it filters all the people that have their birthdays in March?

I tried testing the following but it doesn't seem to select anything

```
  const selectMonths = (selectMonthFilter) => {
    setSelectMonthFilter(selectMonthFilter)
    console.log(selectMonthFilter)
  };

<select value={selectMonthFilter} onChange={event => selectMonths(event.target.value)} >
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/api-test-c4swl?file=/src/pages/home.jsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Provide month option values that match the month portion of the birthdate dateTime string.

   ```
   <label>
     Select Month
     <select
       value={selectMonthFilter}
       onChange={(e) => setSelectMonthFilter(e.currentTarget.value)}
     >
       <option value="">---</option>
       <option value="01">Jan</option>
       <option value="02">Feb</option>
       <option value="03">Mar</option>
       <option value="04">Apr</option>
       <option value="05">May</option>
       <option value="06">Jun</option>
       <option value="07">Jul</option>
       <option value="08">Aug</option>
       <option value="09">Sep</option>
       <option value="10">Oct</option>
       <option value="11">Nov</option>
       <option value="12">Dec</option>
     </select>
   </label>
   ```
2. You can split the birthdate by "T" to get the date prefix, then split that by "-" and take the month part.

   ```
   const getMonthValue = (dateTime) =>
     dateTime.toLowerCase().split("t")[0].split("-")[1];
   ```
3. Once you've the month value you can filter your data by birthdates that match the selected month value. If there is no month to filter by then return true to include all data.

   ```
   {data
     .filter(({ birthdate }) =>
       selectMonthFilter
         ? getMonthValue(birthdate) === selectMonthFilter
         : true
     )
     .map((el) => (
       // map your JSX here
     ))}
   ```

[image: Edit filtering-data-from-api-using-dropdown-in-react]

If you have more filters you can combine them in the single `.filter` callback.

Example:

```
{data
  .filter(({ birthdate, first_name, last_name, preferred_name }) =>
    selectMonthFilter || searchNameFilter
      ? (selectMonthFilter &&
          getMonthValue(birthdate) === selectMonthFilter) ||
        (searchNameFilter &&
          [first_name, last_name, preferred_name]
            .join(" ")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchNameFilter))
      : true
  )
  .map((el) => (
    ...
  ))}
```

It's up to you to decide if all the conditions need to be met (logical **AND** all conditions), or if any of them can match (logical **OR** all conditions).

Comment: So I currently have another filter which filters when you search a name. If I add in the extra divs at the end, I'll have double the data which I don't want. Is there a way to have one data set filter either or?

Comment: @illyabestloli You can do all the filtering in the one `.filter` function. I'll get an update up when I can.

Comment: I added the sandbox link to what I have so far.

Comment: @illyabestloli I see. Is there a reason you want to store the filtered data in state? Are you needing to render two *different* filtered lists? It's derived "state" so it really shouldn't be stored in state, filter the data inline when rendering JSX, which allows you to easily multiple filters.

Comment: I stored the filtered data in state cause it was the only way to get the filtered list. When I tried with the regular list, it didnt filter the names.

Comment: Check this [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/api-test-forked-xk8wx) of your sandbox.

Comment: Hm, I updated the codepen, but there seems to be something I missed since the dropdown doesn't seem to be selecting anything. I console logged the selectMonths function, and it shows "" when I select a month from the dropdown.

Comment: Oh I see why. I forgot to include the numbers in the option tags. I'm still getting an error when I fixed it though saying it can't find undefined of null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235642/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-illyabestloli).

Comment: @illyabestloli Responded in chat in case you've missed it.